# Is using reinterpret_cast after typeid check valid?

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012

If I verify first that pointer to base class is of some type (using `typeid`), is it valid to do `reinterpret_cast` on it to save some performance?

```
class Base {
    virtual ~Base() {}
};
class A : Base {};
class B : Base {};
...
class Z : Base {};
```

and later on somewhere:

```
void fn(Base & msg) {
    const auto & tid = typeid(msg);
    if (tid == typeid(A)) {
        A * ptr = reinterpret_cast<A*>(&msg);
    } else if (tid == typeid(B)) {
        B * ptr = reinterpret_cast<B*>(&msg);
    } ...
    ...
    } else if (tid == typeid(Z)) {
        Z * ptr = reinterpret_cast<Z*>(&msg);
    }
}
```

As far as I can tell, this code works fine as I think it should. However, I'm curious if it's just because I'm lucky or is this actually well defined usage and all? Using `reinterpret_cast` this way.

And before you say to just use normal polymorphism for this, I'm not able to change classes as they are so I need to build this way around it.

Comment: The entire design here looks *incredibly* broken. Just rewriting the relevant stuff you can't change from scratch is definitely worth a thought.

Comment: `reinterpret_cast` does not take the vtable into account. You can lose RTTI and have undefined behavior. So **NO it's not valid**.

Comment: @BaummitAugen would love to but I'm just fixing another team's mess, rewrite is sadly on in the budget :/

Comment: @user1810087 what I wonder is why it's not valid... I mean, after `typeid(*msg) == typeid(Z)` I know it was instance of Z originally anyway no? So why it is not valid to do `reinterpret_cast<Z*>(&msg)` to tell compiler it's instance of Z? I don't understand why taking vtable into account is need at all here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the behaviour would still formally be undefined.

Using `reinterpret_cast` in this way still breaks strict aliasing rules.

If performance *really* is an issue here, then you may well want to avoid `virtual` classes altogether.

Comment: I'll just use dynamic_cast then instead, thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

As with Bathsheba answer, you'll still have undefined behavior.

However, If you don't have virtual inheritance, you can use `static_cast`, which will offset the pointer to the child class correctly:

```
void fn(Base & msg) {
    const auto & tid = typeid(msg);
    if (tid == typeid(A)) {
        A * ptr = static_cast<A*>(&msg);
    } else if (tid == typeid(B)) {
        B * ptr = static_cast<B*>(&msg);
    } else if (tid == typeid(Z)) {
        Z * ptr = static_cast<Z*>(&msg);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes this should work for most cases, unless you have repeated multiple inheritance base classes (eg IUnknown) - I think the compiler will complain about those.